# Crosstab giving only one record when we have multiple present for the specific id

Tags: database, postgresql, pivot-table

The query giving the issue is:

```sql
select * from crosstab
    (
        'SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY evaluation_date,user_id)::int AS sn, user_id,evaluation_id,evaluation_date,evaluation,evaluation_value
        from user_evaluations ue 
        inner join user_evaluation_details ued ON ue.id=ued.evaluation_id where ue.is_deleted=false', --1
        'SELECT id evaluation FROM m_evaluations ORDER BY 1'
    ) as ct (sn int, user_id int, evaluation_id text,evaluation_date timestamp with time zone,"bench_press" text , "body_fat" text ,"deadlift" text ,"front_squat" text ,"height" text ,
             "skeletal_muscle_mass" text ,"type_Level" text ,"weight" text) ORDER BY user_id, evaluation_id,evaluation_date
```

The above query is giving a single record even when (1) query is returning all the data. The crosstab is messing up the transpose and giving out only a single record for a id.
The DDL of the tables used is,

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.user_evaluations (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    user_id int4 NOT NULL,
    evaluation_date timestamptz NOT NULL,
    is_deleted bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT user_evaluations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.user_evaluation_details (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    evaluation_id int4 NULL,
    evaluation varchar(255) NULL,
    evaluation_value varchar(255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_evaluation_details_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.m_evaluations (
    id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    description text NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at timestamptz NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    is_deleted bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT m_evaluations_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I tried out `rank() OVER (ORDER BY evaluation_date,user_id)::int AS sn` in order to fix it but it was hardly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example of how you could change your crosstab query to handle multiple values by using array_agg as the aggregate function:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT ue.user_id,
            ue.evaluation_id,
            ue.evaluation_date,
            ued.evaluation,
            array_agg(ued.evaluation_value) AS values
     FROM user_evaluations ue
     INNER JOIN user_evaluation_details ued ON ue.id = ued.evaluation_id
     WHERE ue.is_deleted = false
     GROUP BY ue.user_id, ue.evaluation_id, ue.evaluation_date, ued.evaluation
     ORDER BY 1, 2, 3',

    'SELECT id evaluation FROM m_evaluations ORDER BY 1'
) AS ct (
    user_id int,
    evaluation_id text,
    evaluation_date timestamp with time zone,
    bench_press text[],
    body_fat text[],
    deadlift text[],
    front_squat text[],
    height text[],
    skeletal_muscle_mass text[],
    type_Level text[],
    weight text[]
)
ORDER BY user_id, evaluation_id, evaluation_date;
```